# Maven Assembly Plugin Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Kindly greetings. I've been trying to use apache maven assembly plugin to generate a fat jar with all dependencies of my application. But when executing java -jar target/cache-maven-0.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar it generates the following output:

**Error: Could not find or load main class cache.SpringBootCacheExampleApplication**

Likely, it is a problem in the MANIFEST.MF:

```
Class-Path: spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.5.5.jar spring-boot-starter
 -2.5.5.jar spring-boot-2.5.5.jar spring-context-5.3.10.jar spring-aop
 -5.3.10.jar spring-expression-5.3.10.jar spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.
 5.5.jar spring-boot-starter-logging-2.5.5.jar logback-classic-1.2.6.j
 ar logback-core-1.2.6.jar slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.
 jar log4j-api-2.14.1.jar jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar jakarta.annotation-a
 pi-1.3.5.jar spring-core-5.3.10.jar spring-jcl-5.3.10.jar snakeyaml-1
 .28.jar spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.5.5.jar spring-boot-actu
 ator-2.5.5.jar jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar jackson-annotations-2.12.5
 .jar jackson-core-2.12.5.jar jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.5.jar micro
 meter-core-1.7.4.jar HdrHistogram-2.1.12.jar LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar s
 pring-boot-starter-webflux-2.5.5.jar spring-boot-starter-json-2.5.5.j
 ar jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.5.jar jackson-module-parameter-names-2.
 12.5.jar spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty-2.5.5.jar reactor-netty-ht
 tp-1.0.11.jar netty-codec-http-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-common-4.1.68.F
 inal.jar netty-buffer-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-transport-4.1.68.Final.j
 ar netty-codec-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-handler-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-
 codec-http2-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-resolver-dns-4.1.68.Final.jar nett
 y-resolver-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-codec-dns-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-re
 solver-dns-native-macos-4.1.68.Final-osx-x86_64.jar netty-transport-n
 ative-unix-common-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.6
 8.Final-linux-x86_64.jar reactor-netty-core-1.0.11.jar netty-handler-
 proxy-4.1.68.Final.jar netty-codec-socks-4.1.68.Final.jar spring-web-
 5.3.10.jar spring-beans-5.3.10.jar spring-webflux-5.3.10.jar reactor-
 core-3.4.10.jar reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar joda-time-2.9.2.jar
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.5.0
Main-Class: cache.SpringBootCacheExampleApplication
```

As you can see, it doesn't contains essential info like the one generated by spring maven plugin:

````
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Implementation-Title: cache-maven
Implementation-Version: 0.0.0
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
Start-Class: cache.SpringBootCacheExampleApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.5.5
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher```
````

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
    
      <build>
        <!--<sourceDirectory>src/main/java/cache</sourceDirectory>-->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <!--<mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>-->
                    <mainClass>cache.SpringBootCacheExampleApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>  <mainClass>cache.SpringBootCacheExampleApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

My project structure:

```html
<pre>cache-service/
        pom.xml
        mvnw
        src/
          main/
            java/
              cache/
                Customer.java
                SpringBootCacheExampleApplication.java (main)
                service/
                  CustomerController.java
            resources/
              application.yml
         target/
           cache-maven-0.0.0.jar
           cache-maven-0.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
           cache-maven-0.0.0.jar.original
           archive-tmp/
             .
           classes/
             application.yml
             cache/
                Customer.class
                SpringBootCacheExampleApplication.class
                service/
                    CustomerController.class
                
           generated-sources/
              annotations/
                .
           maven-archiver/
              pom.properties
           maven-status/
              maven-compiler-plugin/
                compile/
                  default-compile/
                    createdFiles.lst
                    inputFiles.lst<pre>
```

*Any help would be very valued. Thanks.*

Comment: Why not use the spring-boot-maven-plugin? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage

Comment: Thanks. If you read my pom.xml in the plugins section, you wil find that indeed, is the first plugin that I use.

Comment: Oh, and, and about the spring boot maven plugin, it won't generate fat jar with all dependecies, as far as I know, unlike maven assembly plugin. But spring maven plug works well generating a simple jar without dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

I created a Spring Boot project using https://start.spring.io/ and accepting the defaults.

Then built it:
`mvn package`

The jar produced looks like this:

```
$ jar -tvf target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 META-INF/
   453 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/
  5871 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/ClassPathIndexFile.class
  6806 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
  3966 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
...
   293 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarMode.class
  2201 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarModeLauncher.class
  1292 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/TestJarMode.class
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/
  5174 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/SystemPropertyUtils.class
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:46 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:46 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:46 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/demo/
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 META-INF/maven/
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 META-INF/maven/com.example/
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 META-INF/maven/com.example/demo/
   733 Fri Oct 22 08:55:46 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.class
     1 Fri Oct 22 08:55:44 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties
  1222 Thu Oct 21 21:54:48 AEDT 2021 META-INF/maven/com.example/demo/pom.xml
    59 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 META-INF/maven/com.example/demo/pom.properties
     0 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/
1392985 Thu Oct 21 11:45:02 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.5.6.jar
1268455 Thu Oct 21 05:47:28 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-5.3.12.jar
382809 Thu Oct 21 05:46:58 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-5.3.12.jar
697204 Thu Oct 21 05:46:38 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.3.12.jar
288686 Thu Oct 21 05:46:26 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-5.3.12.jar
1566280 Thu Oct 21 11:44:16 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.6.jar
292027 Fri Sep 10 00:27:02 AEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.6.jar
472431 Fri Sep 10 00:15:50 AEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.2.6.jar
 17762 Sat Mar 06 22:13:24 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar
300365 Sat Mar 06 22:11:34 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
  4589 Tue Jul 20 13:55:30 AEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar
 25058 Fri Aug 02 11:08:52 AEST 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
1480024 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-5.3.12.jar
 24440 Thu Oct 21 05:46:04 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jcl-5.3.12.jar
326914 Mon Feb 22 05:55:56 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.28.jar
 41513 Tue Jul 20 13:56:20 AEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar
 29397 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 AEDT 1980 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-2.5.6.jar
   727 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
   212 Fri Oct 22 08:55:48 AEDT 2021 BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

and runs like this:

```
$ java -jar target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)

2021-10-22 08:56:09.037  INFO 88454 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.2 on C02XP03GJGH7 with PID 88454 (/Users/tdavies/tmp/demo/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by tdavies in /Users/tdavies/tmp/demo)
2021-10-22 08:56:09.039  INFO 88454 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-22 08:56:09.501  INFO 88454 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 0.786 seconds (JVM running for 1.155)
```

That's using the default configuration of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which you get with:

```xml
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

This sounds like it does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the maven-assembly-plugin from the pom file, just use the spring-boot-maven-plugin. That worked for me.

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>
                        cache.SpringBootCacheExampleApplication
                    </mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```